# Custom attribute on record fields F#

Tags: reflection, f#

I am trying to declare a custom attribute in a record and trying to read it. It seems to be not working. Please advise.

```
// Custom Attribute for record fields
[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)>]
type Name(x: string) =
    inherit Attribute()
    member _.value = x

// Record type
type User =
    { [<Name("id")>]
      Id: int
      [<Name("email")>]
      Email: string
      [<Name("organization_id")>]
      OrganizationId: option<string> }

// Trying to read the attribute. This is not working. I am getting <null> here.
let parse () =
    FSharpType.GetRecordFields(typeof<User>)
    |> Array.map (fun p -> p.Name, p.GetCustomAttribute(typeof<Name>, false))
    |> Array.iter (fun (t, a) -> printfn "%s : %A" t a)
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code fixes the problem. For more detailed answer, refer this [link](https://forums.fsharp.org/t/custom-attribute-on-record-fields/2094/2).

```
// Changing to property instead of field
[<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)>]
type Name(x: string) =
    inherit Attribute()
    member _.value = x
```